# Dynamic Tableview cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I wanted to create the dynamic table cell view that can align element according to the text in the label. The cell height differs as the text in the label. What are the best approaches to design this type of designs.
[image: how to get exact alignment in the table view cell as label text is in three lines other element align horizontally in centre i don't want to truncate the tail i want full text.]

[image: if the text is in two lines sample.]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can create the right label with same height as left label. Then try to align text in middle. For that you can create custom label that align text in middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can set for example in your **viewDidLoad**:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Then, when you draw your xib cell, you can follow this schema:

```
+-view----------------+
|       |             |
|    -label-          |
|       |             | 
| +-subview--------+  |
| |      |   |     |  | 
|-| -label-label-  |--|
| |      |   |     |  | 
| |   -label-      |  | 
| |      |         |  |
| +----------------+  |
|        |            |
|     -label-         |
|        |            | 
+---------------------+
```

where each label have top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints setted.
If you need to compact a labels group you can add subview to include them inside it.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro Ornano for the reply and solution. Is there any way to use stack views that where introduced in iOS 9 ?

Comment: Sure, I think stack views are the future. I like for example the introduction here http://www.appcoda.com/stack-views-intro/ but for now if you want to make an iOS 8.x compatible you cannot use them as explained in the official guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/

Comment: Thanks for the Valuable information. Can you please provide me some links for Autolayout and Constraints so that it will be easy for me to understand the methods how their mechanism work.

Comment: You can take a look a this guide: https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2 , it's very rapid and clean. 
P.S. If you think this answer is correct please select as correct answer for this page, thank you

Answer (score 0):

For alignment:

You can create the right label with same height as left label.
Then try to align text in middle. For that you can subclass UILabel class and change the text rect alignment to middle.

```
For Dynamic Height:
 1. Use auto layout when creating your table view cells.
 2. Set the table view rowHeight to equal UITableViewAutomaticDimension.
 3. Set the estimatedRowHeight or implement the height estimation delegate method.

    Pro Tip: the trick to getting auto layout to work on a UITableViewCell is to ensure you have constraints to pin each subview on all sides — that is, each subview should have leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints.
    Furthermore, you need a clear line of constraints going from the top to the bottom of the contentView. This ensures that auto layout correctly determines the height of the contentView based on its subviews.
    The tricky part is that Interface Builder often won’t warn you if you’re missing some of these constraints; auto layout simply doesn’t return the correct heights when you run the project. For example, it may return 0 for the cell height, which is a clue that your constraints need more work.
    If you run into issues when working with your own projects, try adjusting your constraints until the above criteria are met.


For Detail, please refer to original source of above text is https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift
```